# Exception message in JCodemodel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I am using JCodemodel to generate java classes dynamically. Below is the code for creating a switch statement whose the default case would be to throw an Exception.

```
JSwitch valueswitch;

AbstractJClass exception = ref(IllegalArgumentException.class);

valueswitch._default()
          .body()
          ._throw(JExpr._new(exception));
```

The generated class looks like below

```
public static Example switchCode(String code) {
        switch (code) {
            case "1":
            {
                return A;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to add a message to the exception thrown like

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid code "+ code);
```

How can i achieve this in JCodemodel. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the statement to the exception constructor:

```
    valueswitch._default()
            .body()
            ._throw(JExpr._new(exception)
                    .arg(
                            JOp.plus(JExpr.lit("Invalid code "), codeParam)
                    ));
```